# My HTML5 animation is crashing firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas

I have exported a HTML5 canvas animation out of flash by changing its document type before exporting it. It seems to be playing fine on my devices (iMac, iPhone and iPad) but when testing on a colleagues PC the animation seems to be either crashing firefox or flickering the different elements within the animation. This is only happening in firefox (the most up to date version).

I haven't found any solutions to this issue so far, however I am new to HTML5 and any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to post the code and/or any errors reported by the browser console if you want anyone to help.

Comment: you should past some code or create a plunkr/fiddle or give a link to your site

Comment: Echoing the other comments, we cannot help without seeing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that is misbehaving. Without that ... we would just be guessing. :-)